# PHP Read Large text file line by line and store into array

Tags: php

I am trying to parse a large log file and store data to array.
The above test code works fine on localhost, but on server it returns "The connection was reset" error on firefox and "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" on Chrome.

Is there a way to optimize this script in order to run on server too?

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 990);
ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");
ini_set('max_input_vars', 3000);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

set_time_limit(200);

function startsWith ($string, $startString){
    $len = strlen($startString);
    return (substr($string, 0, $len) === $startString);
}

function append_string ($str1, $str2){
    $str1 .=$str2;
    return $str1;
}

function readTheFile($file) {
  $i = 0;
  $handle = fopen($file, "rb") or die("Unable to open file!");

  while(!feof($handle))  {
      $line = fgets($handle);
      if(!startsWith($line,"::1") && !startsWith($line,"127.0.0.1") || $line != ''){
        $line = str_replace('"', '', explode (' ', $line));
        $line = str_replace('[', '', $line);
        $line = str_replace(']', '', $line);
        if(array_key_exists("5",$line) && array_key_exists("8",$line)){
          if($line[5] == "GET" || $line[5] == "POST" || $line[5] == "PUT" || $line[5] == "HEAD" || $line[5] == "DELETE" || $line[5] == "PATCH" || $line[5] == "OPTIONS"){
           if(is_numeric($line[8])){
              $dt = explode(":", $line[3], 2);
              $date = $dt[0];
              $time = substr($dt[1], 0, strrpos( $dt[1], ':'));
              $time = substr($time, 0, strrpos($time, ':'));
              $time = append_string($time, ':00');


              $recs[$i]['Date']  = $date;
              $recs[$i]['Time']  = $time;
              $recs[$i]['Method']   = $line[5];
              $recs[$i]['StatusCode'] = $line[8];


              unset($dt);
              unset($date);
              unset($time);
              $i++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    unset($line);
  }

  fclose($handle);
  return $recs;
}
$records = [];

$records = readTheFile('access.log');
echo json_encode($records);
?>
```

Comment: On the server, examine the web server's error log. I see you have error reporting turned up here, but I can't recall for certain if exceeding execution time or memory limit errors will make it to the output stream. They would be logged though.

Comment: I don't see any glaring issues like large array copies or faulty loops, anything beyond what you have now would probably be micro-optimization and not affect the outcome. The ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE does sound like either memory limit or execution time were breached

Comment: What is the size of the logfile you're accessing? And what is the estimated maximum length of a single line? The Connection reset error will be a time out of the webserver, which will probably be less than the time out on your development environment.

Comment: The log file contains ~600000 lines, and if I comment the ini_set("memory_limit","1024M"), I get: " Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) ".

Comment: Is this on a shared hosting server or on a private server? Shared hosts will implement their own resource limits in ways that may not play nicely with PHP settings.

Comment: Yes, it is on shared hosting.